# Espião está sendo chamado mas função não é coberta no Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

Possuo um `sidenav` e dentro desse `sidenav` tenho o componente `header`:

```
<div>
   <app-header id="header" (openSidenavEmitter)="openSidenav()"></app-header>
</div>
```

Meu componente header possui um `Event Emitter` que quando o usuário clica em um determinado ícone, ele emite pro componente de `sidenav` que deve ser aberto:

```
@Output() openSidenavEmitter = new EventEmitter();
openSidenav() {
   this.openSidenavEmitter.emit()
}
```

No meu componente `sidenav`, quando recebe esse evento, ele chama a função `"openSideNav()"`:

```
openSidenav() {
   this.showSidenav = true;
}
```

Estou tentando fazer um teste unitário que cubra a função `openSidenav()`, apesar do meu espião estar sendo chamado, no report do karma a função `openSidenav()` ainda não aparece como coberta. Este foi o teste implementado no componente de sidenav:

```
it('should open sidenav when user click in hamburg icon', () => {
   const spyOnOpenSidenav = spyOn(component, 'openSidenav')
   const header = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#header'));
   header.triggerEventHandler('openSidenavEmitter', {});
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(spyOnOpenSidenav).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

Apesar do meu teste ser executado com sucesso, a função 'openSidenav' ainda é mostrada como não coberta no relatório de testes do karma.
Como posso cobrir esse tipo de cenário no componente pai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi necessário utilizar o método `.callThrough()`:

```
const spyOnOpenSidenav = spyOn(component, 'openSidenav').and.callThrough()
```

Isso se deve ao fato de que um espião substitui a chamada da função por um stub sem a implementação real da função, servindo apenas para confirmar que a função foi chamada e/ou chamada com argumentos específicos.
Segundo a documentação do Jasmine:

> Ao encadear o espião com `and.callThrough`, o espião ainda rastreará
> todas as chamadas para ele, mas, além disso, delegará a implementação
> real.